Can an audio isolation transformer between a preamplifier and an amplifier cause the amplifier's fuse to blow?
I'm building a microphone preamplifier. I was having problems with hum (intermittent ground hum when touching the case) and decided to try adding an audio isolation transformer (600 ohm : 600 ohm) before its output. The circuit is powered by AA batteries.
I wired this up and then tried it out plugged into a guitar amplifier, an amplifier that I'd been using before (with success), to test the circuit before I added the transformer.
The amplifier blew its fuse after a couple of seconds of loud low buzz/hum.  This was a surprise, because as I understand it a 1-to-1 transformer doesn't change the voltage or current, and for a fuse to blow the current would have to go over the fuse's limit.
What about the signal did the amplifier not like? What could have gone wrong?
To be clear, The preamp was working without the transformer  (other than the occasional ground hum. which I've now worked around with some electric tape). The only thing that changed was putting in the transformer right before the output jack. the transformer can't be wired up backwards because it's 1:1. right? so that would seem to eliminate some error in connecting the transformer.

Perhaps the transformer was wired incorrectly. Or not. Insufficient information.

How is your preamp powered (a self-contained battery perhaps?). In some cases the connecting cable carries both DC and the AC(audio) signal, eliminating the need for batteries. In that case, a 1:1 transformer shorts out the DC source.

We really don't know what you wired and how. Chanses are a loose or incorrect connection between amp input and your device output. Since you had hum to begin with, a loose ground between your device and amp means all the amp sees is mains hum at a significant voltage which it simply tries to amplify to the speaker like it would do to any signal, and then damage because it would need more power/current handling ability to be able to do that.

@glen_geek yes, a self-contained battery. The guts of the thing is a little pcb with a SSM2167 chip. 2 AA batteries power it. input comes from an onboard contact mic, output goes to a 1/4" jack.

@Justme but the real core of my question is why would the addition of the transformer cause that? because the thing worked fine, with the same amp, same guitar cord connecting to the amp, albeit with the hum. but then adding the isolation transformer and boom.

after a little more research I realized maybe the fuse blowing was because a tube blew in the guitar amp (a Fender Blues Jr). But i looked at the tubes and they seem fine.

@steev To figure it out I was asking you to provide more info. We don't still know if you made some incorrect connections to explain what happened. We don't know how your preamp was powered either. Maybe your preamp saw hum and drove the hum through transformer to guitar amp. We have no clue what your preamp looks like. In order to replicate your experiment, we need to know what was connected and how.

Are you sure, that the preamplifier can drive this transformer? The datasheet on page 8 says, that the load should be > 5 kohm.

The SSM2167 amplifier IC has 40dB of gain. If the mic wires were loose, it received mains hum and amplified it to levels that damage the guitar amp, which also has a huge gain. Only unamplified things or things with low enough output voltage ability should be connected into guitar amps that are intended to take in only low enough voltages. I am not saying it did happen but do verify yourself - the audio isolation transformer may have nothing to do with it, or it might have been incorrectly connected. There is not enough info to try buying what you bought and connecting them the way you did.

looks like @Jens has the likely answer. there's an impedance mismatch between the preamp circuit and that transformer. although i've also discovered after replacing the fuse that i have a bad tube. But is it a coincidence or did the problem circuit cause the tube failure? I probably won't ever know because i'm giving up on using this transformer... thanks everyone.

@steev if the mic preamp can't drive the isolation transformer, then it can't. It does not result into a blown tube or fuse. The likely culprit is elsewhere. I still think your connections made the mic preamp to output mains hum at full blaze or at least the guitar amp to see it did. You never said anything about if the connections were verified to be correct or not faulty, and if you used mains powered supply instead of batteries then it may have caused problems. You don't give enough info to determine what was the problem. If I were to replicate the experiment, you must explain the setup.

@Justme it's powered by battery, as i said above. and again, this worked (and still works) without the transformer.

If what is said above is too little information to give a concrete answer I don't think it makes any difference keeping on insisting on using that. It's better to give more new information,.if you're actually interested in getting an answer to the question.

And if the design info is confidential -(Which could be understandable - but then the question doesn't fit the format of a public Q/A site) - then what you need is not a Q/A site but a consultancy agency that can help you design your product.

@MrGerber and others -  it seems like there's a fundamental misunderstanding about what I'm asking. I'm not asking for THE reason why what happened  happened, or for someone to exactly replicate the conditions so they can say exactly what went wrong. I'm just asking for some GUESSES, speculation, about possible things that MIGHT have happened. Some simple brainstorming. There is no amount of further info I could  give that would allow anyone to exactly replicate and give THE answer, because it's highly idiosyncratic (built inside a certain metal chocolate tin, mic glued on in a certain way,)

If that kind of loose discussion is not appropriate for this forum, i apologize and will go somewhere else. thanks.
